# Django Query Set into json object

Tags: python, django

Below I'm trying to get a query make is a json object, so that in my template using jQuery I can loop over it.

**My View**

```
from django.core import serializers
objectQuerySet = Recipient.objects.filter(incentiveid=incentive).values("mobile", "countryid")
data = serializers.serialize("json", objectQuerySet)
```

return render_to_response('smssend.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

**I'm getting the following error.**

```
Non-model object (<type 'dict'>) encountered during serialization

Request Method:
```

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#values() "returns dictionaries when used as an iterable" - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

I think you need python's json#dumps(dict) here